# Delay in Simulation of Output with regard to Input

Tags: vhdl, modelsim

I am making a MultiLevel Car Parking system module with consist of common entry and exit, The idea is that, when I get input stimulus  from signal `car entry` or `car exit`, It will check the car's Type and then the output should display the level reserved for the particular type where, the car should go, If the slots reserves for particular type is full then the display should output as such. The code gets stimulated through the output gets displayed only after the next clock cycle after the input stimulus is given.

I have tried using a different if-else block for counting operations and also with different process using a flag, and tried to change it to different if-else blocks, but it's still the same. I am beginner to vhdl the execution of statements is quite confusing, and online search is of little help, please help me where did I go wrong?

```
library ieee;
    use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
    use ieee.Numeric_std.all; 
            use work.Parking_Package.all;

entity CarPark is 
port(     clk :in std_logic;
      rst : in std_logic;
      car_in : in std_logic;
      Car_out : in std_logic;
      Ent_car_type : car_type;
          Ext_car_type : car_type;
      Status : out level
    );
end CarPark;

architecture behave of CarPark is 
signal count : counter;
begin         
SLOT_CHECKING: process(rst,clk)
begin 
        if(rst= '1')then
    count <= (others => 0);
    Status <= FULL;

        elsif(rising_edge(clk))then
    if(car_in )then       
                     case(Ent_car_type)is                                    
    when Admin =>                                            
                    if(count(Admin) < 5) then                                                
                            Status <= L1;                                                
                            count(Admin) <= count(Admin) +1;
        else
                         Status <= FULL;                                 
                    end if;
    when Staff =>
         if(count(Staff) < 5) then
            Status <= L2;
            count(Staff) <= count(Staff) + 1;
        else
          Status <= FULL;
               end case;                                                                         
            end if;
      elsif(car_out)then                                 
            case(Ext_car_type)is                                     
        when Admin =>                                            
                            if(count(Admin) >0) then
               Status <= L1a;
               count(Admin) <= count(Admin) - 1;
            else
               count(Admin)<= 0;                  
            end if;
        when Staff =>
            if(count(Staff) >0) then
                Status <= L2a;
                count(Staff) <= count(Staff) - 1;
            else
                count(Staff) <= 0;  
            end if;
     end process;
 end behave;
```

The user defined packages is given below

```
library ieee;
        use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
        use ieee.Numeric_std.all;
package Parking_Package is

     type car_type is (Admin, Staff);

     type level is (L1, L2a, FULL);

     type counter is array (Staff downto Admin) of integer range 0 to 22;

     end Parking_Package;

package body Parking_Package is

end Parking_Package;
```

After initializing using reset, I give input of `car_in` as 1 and 
`car_type` as Admin, The output gets displayed as `L1` in the **Next Clock**
and if I force the value of `car_type` as `staff`, The corresponding output is simulated in the next clock cycle.

![ScreenShot Simulation] https://i.stack.imgur.com/9e8Gg.jpg

Comment: I don't understand very well your problem. The behavior of your simulation seems to be good.

Comment: @Gautitho Please refer the Image in the link, Whenever the `Ent_Car_type` is forced a value the output `Status` shows the change in the Next clock cycle. I want the output to show the change in the same clock cycle, i.e when the change input is given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, some comments :

- Your application (MultiLevel Car Parking) is not very adapted to VHDL language. It's too high level. Your coding style is a bit object oriented (type and variable names).
- There are syntax errors in your code (I assume you already know it because You achieve to have a simulation screen).
- The behavior that you expect on the first clock cycle implies that your output will be the product of combinational logic. It's better to have outputs directly from flip flops.

Then the code that you can use to have the expected behavior with 2 process (One purely sequential, the other purely combinational) :

```
    signal current_count        : counter;
    signal next_count           : counter;
    signal current_status       : level;
    signal next_status          : level;

begin

    SEQ : process(rst_tb, clk_tb)
    begin

        if (rst_tb = '1') then

            current_count   <= (others => 0);
            current_status  <= FULL;

        elsif (rising_edge(clk_tb)) then

            current_count   <= next_count;
            current_status  <= next_status;

        end if;

     end process;

     SLOT_CHECKING : process(current_count, current_status, car_in, car_out, Ent_car_type, Ext_car_type)
     begin

        next_count  <= current_count;
        next_status <= current_status;

        if (car_in = '1') then       

            case (Ent_car_type) is

                when Admin =>                                            
                    if (current_count(Admin) < 5) then                                                
                        next_status         <= L1;                                                
                        next_count(Admin)   <= current_count(Admin) + 1;
                    else
                        next_status         <= FULL;                                 
                    end if;

                when Staff =>
                    if (current_count(Staff) < 5) then
                        next_status         <= L2;
                        next_count(Staff)   <= current_count(Staff) + 1;
                    else
                        next_status         <= FULL;                                                                       
                    end if;

            end case;

        elsif (car_out = '1') then    

            case (Ext_car_type) is  

                when Admin =>                                            
                    if (current_count(Admin) > 0) thenremarques
                        next_status         <= L1a;
                        next_count(Admin)   <= current_count(Admin) - 1;
                    else
                        next_count(Admin)   <= 0;                  
                    end if;

                when Staff =>
                    if (current_count(Staff) > 0) then
                        next_status         <= L2a;
                        next_count(Staff)   <= current_count(Staff) - 1;
                    else
                        next_count(Staff)   <= 0;  
                    end if;

            end case;

         end if;

    end process;

    count   <= next_count   ;
    Status  <= next_status  ;
```

Warning, with this code the outputs are directly from combinational logic : It's not recommended but it is the only way to get the behavior you expect.

If this application is only a practise, I advice you too to take another example more adapted to VHDL : filter, SPI communication, processing unit, ...

Comment: If you need more explanations, don't hesitate to ask :)

Comment: Thanks! @ Gautitho, This is working as I wanted, And yes, I am beginner in VHDL, Shifted from sequential programming. It's Hard to understand the flow, Could you please Explain how the your method works? Like I am not able to grasp the flow of  execution of the code.

Comment: And you have mentioned that My coding style is bit too high level, Could you specify what is expected of, Thanks in advance.

Comment: VHDL is very different in his philosophy than other programming languages (It is not a programming language, it's an hardware description language). I think it's very hard to learn VHDL by yourself counter to programming langage with which you can do a lot of things without understanding well the wheels under the surface. For VHDL (or Verilog), it is necessary to have theorical luggage on boolean algebra, digital electronics and computer science to do something really functionnal. I will not be able to explain you all of these in comments of this post but I will try to give you some keys.

Comment: When you code VHDL, you have to always keep in mind the digital circuit corresponding your code. Think in term of execution flow is a mistake : it's not a programm you are executing, it's a digital circuit you are describing. If we simplify a lot : In a program, each line is executed sequentialy (one after another) ; in VHDL, each line is "executed" concurrently (at the same time of the others). In the example, the first process *SEQ* will create flipflops (memory, outputs available on clock edge), the second *SLOT_CHECKING* is purely combinational (computing, outputs available immediately).

Comment: I can help you on specific questions but for global questions I advice you to follow some tutorial on the internet for more global informations. About your coding style, I told that mainly about the name of your variables that are very high level (car_type : Admin, Staff, ...). Philosophically it's a bit surprising but it's totally correct.

Comment: Oh, that is quite a difference you have pointed out, Thank you I will look into this perspective, from now on. This is more in lines of having a digital circuit in mind while writing a VHDL code, If I am correct.